# ExtJS/Script# - Adding a double-click event to a button

Tags: extjs, extjs3, script#

Creating a calculator-like dialog, I noticed that quickly clicking on a button in IE will *not* fire the click event twice (Chrome/FF work as expected), but rather throws the click event, then a double-click event.  Experimenting with some simple code, I essentially want to duplicate this behavior:

```
<script language=javascript>
function minus(num)
{
  var i = document.getElementById('0001');
  if (i.value > 1)
  {
    i.value -= num;
    return true;
  }
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="minus(1);"  ondblclick="minus(1);" value="minus">
<input type="text" id="0001" name="0001" value=10>
```

I need to do this in ExtJS 3.1, but my efforts have been stymied.  Here is the code I have tried:

```
Button btn = new Ext.Button(new ButtonConfig()
                            .text(text)
            .tooltip(tooltip)
                            .tooltipType("title")
                            .scope(this)
                            .handler(delgateFunction)
                            .x(x)
                            .y(y)
                            .tabIndex(_tabIndex++)
                            .width(width).height(height)
                            .ToDictionary());
btn.addListener("mouseenter", new EventHandler(mouseHandler));
btn.addListener("mouseover", new EventHandler(mouseHandler));
btn.addListener("mouseout", new EventHandler(mouseLeave));
if (Ext.isIE)
{
  //btn.on("dblclick", new EventHandler(DoubleClick));
  //btn.addListener("dblclick", new EventHandler(DoubleClick));
  //btn.addListener("ondblclick", new EventHandler(DoubleClick));
}
```

None of those three lines seemed to work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr. Zhu led me to the correct answer:

```
Events.AddEvent(_zeroBtn.getEl().dom, "dblclick", DoubleClickZero);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following after the button is rendered:

```
btn.el.on("dblclick", new EventHandler(DoubleClick));
```

Ext.Button itself hasn't the "dblclick" event (check the api) while its underlying el(Ext.Element) has.

Complete Sample:

```
new Ext.Button({id:'btn', text:'dblclick', renderTo:Ext.getBody() });
Ext.getCmp('btn').el.on('dblclick', function(){alert('db click');});
```

Comment: Not quite - but it put me on the right path - so thank you.  The solution I found was this:  
  

`Events.AddEvent(_zeroBtn.getEl().dom, "dblclick", DoubleClickZero);`  
  
  
Thanks again.

Comment: I am using Script# (C# code converted to JavaScript).  Thanks again.